# sending JSON data to a view in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm doing some filtering on my json and saving it in a driver variable. I the driver variable is returning JSON data and i want to send them as they are to the view without changes.

## *my question is: how can i send the driver var to the view ?*

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
rp(options)
    .then(function (repos) {
        var obj = repos;
        var driver = _.filter( obj.features, ['id', 'tmp_location.20658']);
        console.log(driver);        })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Delete failed...
    });
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `res.render` to `rp.then` and pass `driver` it as another property in `res.render` parameters.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
rp(options)
    .then(function (repos) {
        var obj = repos;
        var driver = _.filter( obj.features, ['id', 'tmp_location.20658']);
        console.log(driver);
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', driver: driver });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Delete failed...
    });

});
```

Please read this also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

**Edit:**

You should also use `next` in `catch` handler

```
.catch(function (err) {
    next(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
rp(options)
.then(function (repos) {
    var obj = repos;
    var driver = _.filter( obj.features, ['id', 'tmp_location.20658']);
    console.log(driver);        })
.catch(function (err) {
    // Delete failed...
});
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' , data:driver});
});
```